# How to run two separate mocha test files from a single testrunner.html?

Tags: mocha.js

Hello: I am running a mocha test from the browser using an html link [testrunner.html](https://gist.github.com/shaohua/7441895).

I have two mocha test files which i want to include in the testrunner.html. Can this be done?

If i have to run the mocha test `via the terminal`, i would have a `main.js` file which will have inclusions to both the mocha test files, such as: `require('./test1.js')` and `require('./test2.js')`. It works.

Question is: How can i do the same if i have to initiate both mocha test files via a single html file?

**test1.js**

```
describe('suite1', function(){
    it('case1', function(){...});
    it('case2', function(){...});
});
```

**test2.js**

```
describe('suite2', function(){
    it('case1', function(){...});
    it('case2', function(){...});
});
```

**main.js**

```
describe('test1', function(){
    require('./test1.js');
    require('./test2.js');
});
```

**testrunner.html**

Similar to: [testrunner.html](https://gist.github.com/shaohua/7441895)

Comment: The answer is the same as the earlier question you asked. You show a `main.js` that uses `require`. As the answer here is the same as the answer I gave you earlier: if you want to use `require` for Mocha tests run in the browser you need to prepack your tests with Webpack or Browserify or you need to use a loader that will load your tests at run time like RequireJS or SystemJS.

Comment: @Louis, added an additional note to original qusetion. I still use `requirejs` for loading the modules. However, the problem i stated above relates to including a `describe` within a `describe`. Can i still use the loader to do this? if Yes, Can you kindly provide some directions? Many thanks.